# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found - Dell-System-Inspiron-15-7000-Series-7537

Tags: wireless, dell, intel-wireless

I just installed **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**, however, I cannot use the **Intel Corporation Wireless 72600 (Wireless-N 7260)** component.

I´m getting this error message: **No Wi-Fi Adapter Found**.

Could you please assist?

I cannot access the internet.

For more information or further details, please see the outputs below.

**lspci**

```
carlos@carlos-Dell-System-Inspiron-15-7000-Series-7537:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 63)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
carlos@carlos-Dell-System-Inspiron-15-7000-Series-7537:~$
```

**lshw -C network**

```
carlos@carlos-Dell-System-Inspiron-15-7000-Series-7537:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 63
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:11:12:23
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-15-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:46 memory:d0500000-d0501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: enp3s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 78:45:c4:c9:f5:fa
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
carlos@carlos-Dell-System-Inspiron-15-7000-Series-7537:~$
```

**rfkill list**

```
carlos@carlos-Dell-System-Inspiron-15-7000-Series-7537:~$ rfkill list
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
carlos@carlos-Dell-System-Inspiron-15-7000-Series-7537:~$
```

**cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell-rbtn.conf**

```
carlos@carlos-Dell-System-Inspiron-15-7000-Series-7537:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell-rbtn.conf

carlos@carlos-Dell-System-Inspiron-15-7000-Series-7537:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please read the answer again and try to run the command till you don't have an empty conf file. It looks like you fail to run the command properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wireless adapter is blocked by `rfkill`.

Check if there is a physical switch that may be off, or a BIOS setting.

In case there is no way to switch it on, you can disable `dell-rbtn` by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell-rbtn.conf <<< "blacklist dell_rbtn"
```

This is ONE COMMAND. Please don't run it partially.

Reboot to apply.

Comment: I just followed these steps:

**Steps**

· Enter _sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell-rbtn.conf_
· Enter my password

It looks like the terminal is **stuck**.

Any advice?

Comment: I had to close the terminal, however; I checked the _modprobe.d_ folder and _blacklist-dell-rbtn.conf_ was there. After that, I rebooted, however; the issue persist. Any advice?

Comment: Why did you run only a part of the command? That's why it didn't work.

Comment: I just followed these steps: 

**Steps**
· Enter `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell-rbtn.conf <<< "blacklist dell_rbtn"`
· Reboot the device.

The issue persist. Any advice?

Comment: Did `rfkill list` output change?

Comment: Actually no.

The output for `rfkill list` is the same.

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell-rbtn.conf ` to your question.

Comment: Most likely you made an error there. Don't type commands. Copy and paste them.

Comment: You have an empty file. It should contain `blacklist dell_rbtn`

Comment: This issue has been resolved.

In summary, the resolution steps:

**Steps**

· Access the terminal.
· Enter this command: `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell-rbtn.conf <<< "blacklist dell_rbtn"`
· Reboot the computer.
· Access the pertinent network.
· Authenticate against the network.

I really appreciate all your patience and help **Pilot6**

**Best support ever!**